# Ormlite saves the Date format with Arabic digits in the database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have an issue with saving the date using Ormlite when the default locale in the app is "ar" Arabic and the device language is Arabic. The date is saved in SQLite with Arabic digits, but I need the Ormlite to save the data with locale English digits.
I tried using this persisterClass but it did not solve my issue:

```
    public class DateStringSQLiteType extends DateStringType {

    private static SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);


    protected static final DateStringFormatConfig dateFormatConfig = new DateStringFormatConfig(
            sdfDateTime.toPattern());

    private static final DateStringSQLiteType singleTon = new DateStringSQLiteType();

    public static DateStringSQLiteType getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }

    private DateStringSQLiteType() {
        super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Convert a default string object and return the appropriate argument to a
     * SQL insert or update statement.
     */
    @Override
    public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType fieldType, String defaultStr)
            throws SQLException {
        DateStringFormatConfig formatConfig = convertDateStringConfig(
                fieldType, dateFormatConfig);
        try {
            // we parse to make sure it works and then format it again
            return normalizeDateString(formatConfig, defaultStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw SqlExceptionUtil.create("Problems with field " + fieldType
                    + " parsing default date-string '" + defaultStr
                    + "' using '" + formatConfig + "'", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the SQL argument object extracted from the results associated with
     * column in position columnPos. For example, if the type is a date-long
     * then this will return a long value or null.
     *
     * @param fieldType Associated FieldType which may be null.
     * @throws SQLException If there is a problem accessing the results data.
     */
    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results,
                                 int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return results.getString(columnPos);
    }

    /**
     * Return the object converted from the SQL arg to java. This takes the
     * database representation and converts it into a Java object. For example,
     * if the type is a date-long then this will take a long which is stored in
     * the database and return a Date.
     *
     * @param fieldType Associated FieldType which may be null.
     * @param sqlArg    SQL argument converted with
     *                  {@link #resultToSqlArg(FieldType, DatabaseResults, int)} which
     *                  will not be null.
     */
    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos)
            throws SQLException {
        String value = (String) sqlArg;
        DateStringFormatConfig formatConfig = convertDateStringConfig(
                fieldType, dateFormatConfig);
        try {
            return parseDateString(formatConfig, value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw SqlExceptionUtil.create("Problems with column " + columnPos
                    + " parsing date-string '" + value + "' using '"
                    + formatConfig + "'", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert a Java object and return the appropriate argument to a SQL insert
     * or update statement.
     */
    @Override
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object obj) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = convertDateStringConfig(fieldType,
                dateFormatConfig).getDateFormat();
        return dateFormat.format((Date) obj);
    }

    /**
     * @throws SQLException If there are problems creating the config object. Needed for
     *                      subclasses.
     */
    @Override
    public Object makeConfigObject(FieldType fieldType) {
        String format = fieldType.getFormat();
        if (format == null) {
            return dateFormatConfig;
        } else {
            return new DateStringFormatConfig(format);
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Ormlite save the Date format with Arabic Digits in the database]

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can convert your date time to timestamp value then save as a String or Double...